# Django view objects filter with timezone.now().date or timezone.now().time-> expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django, object, filter, timezone

Hi i have some Django 11 project, my model look like

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='events/%Y/%m/%d')
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    start_time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)
    stop_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    stop_time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now)

    place = models.ForeignKey('places.Place', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey('companies.Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and my view look like

```
def place_website(request, place_id):

    place_template = get_template('room.html')

    place_obj = Place.objects.filter(id=place_id)

    # filter for event obejts only for requested place, filtered for now and next events
    place_event_now = Event.objects.filter(place=place_id, start_date=timezone.now().date, stop_date__gte=timezone.now().date)

    place_events_next = Event.objects.filter(place=place_id, start_date=timezone.now(), stop_date__gte=timezone.now()).order_by('start_time')

    place_context = {
        'place_obj': place_obj,
        'place_event_now': place_event_now,
        'place_events_next': place_events_next,
    }

    return HttpResponse(place_template.render(place_context))
```

the thing i want to manage is to pass to template the list of filtered Event objects based on time.

Lets pick this line

```
place_event_now = Event.objects.filter(place=place_id, start_date=timezone.now().date, stop_date__gte=timezone.now().date)
```

it couse error "expected string or bytes-like object" but when i remove ".date" from "timezone.now()" error disappear (then filter do nothing) but i want to compare date to date and time to time.

How to do this properly ?

This approach to filter objects in view rather than in template is proper?

**######  UPDATE   ########**

Its werid because after correction now i have no error but queryset is not filtered properly, look like only two first parameter is filtering ok and the another two is causing empty queryset.

```
place_event_now = Event.objects.filter(place=place_id, start_date=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), start_time__lte=timezone.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), stop_time__gte=timezone.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

I my database time is saved in format **H:M:S** and timezone.now().time() has different format so i modified filter with **.strftime**  this didnt help, what i wont is to limit "**place_event_now**" queryset to particular object/objects that come true with condition   **start_time < currenttime < stop_time.**

Another case is with **place_event_next**

```
place_events_next = Event.objects.filter(place=place_id, start_date=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), stop_date__gte=timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), start_time__gt=timezone.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')).order_by('start_time')
```

Event when i filter objects that **start_time** is greater than **timezone.now()** they still are in queryset.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You miss the parentheses `.date()`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: @SébastienDeprez  guys this is it !!!  thanks a lot !!!

Comment: update,after make fixes still filtering issue, am i using filter improperly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need call `date` to `date()`
replace

```
filter(place=place_id, start_date=timezone.now().date, stop_date__gte=timezone.now().date)
#                                                  ^^^                                 ^^^
```

to

```
filter(place=place_id, start_date=timezone.now().date(), stop_date__gte=timezone.now().date())
#                                                  ^^^                                 ^^^
```

Comment: may be you need `start_date__gte=` instead of `start_date=` add __gte

Comment: i want to limit the queryset to events for today, so i think it should be start_date without __gte  ?  right ?

Comment: does it help you `start_date__date`?

Comment: its working ok with date, but please read my update of case after i applied fixes, there is problem with time i think

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out that **timezone.now()**  return time not in my current timezone, i change it to  **timezone.localtime()**   and everything working perfect !!!